The body might complete normally, causing 'null' to be returned, but the return type, 'VoidCallback', is a potentially non-nullable type
void deleteProduct(Product product, int index) {
    adminController.DeleteProduct(
        context: context,
        product: product,
        onSuccess: (){
           products.removeAt(index);
            setState(() {});//refresh page
        }
        );
  }

it show:

The body might complete normally, causing 'null' to be returned, but the return type, 'VoidCallback', is a potentially non-nullable type.
Try adding either a return or a throw statement at the end.

Here is the DeleteProduct function:
void DeleteProduct(
      {required BuildContext context,
      required Product product,
      required VoidCallback onSuccess()}) async {
    final userProvider = Provider.of<UserProvider>(context,
        listen: false); //get the current user
    try {
      http.Response res = await http.post(
        Uri.parse("$uri/admin/delete-product"),
        headers: <String, String>{
          'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
          'stamp': userProvider
              .user.stamp, //to identify the user of this product data
        },
        body: jsonEncode({'id': product.id}),
      );
      print("product deleting at front end");
      httpErrorHandler(
        context: context,
        response: res,
        onSuccess: onSuccess,
      );
    } catch (e) {
      ShowSnackBar(context, e.toString());
      print(e.toString());
      rethrow;
    }
  }


Do what it says.  Add an empty "return;" to the callback function.

Try to change VoidCallback onSuccess() to VoidCallback onSuccess on DeleteProduct function arguments, which is the correct way to specify a callback that takes no arguments and returns no value.

VoidCallback onSuccess() declares a function that takes no arguments and returns a VoidCallback (which is a typedef to void Function()).  That is, onSuccess is declared to return another function, and that other function should return nothing (void).
You probably meant to declare onSuccess as a function that returns nothing, so either do:

VoidCallback onSuccess.  That declares onSuccess as a VoidCallback instead of as returning a VoidCallback.
void onSuccess() (or nowadays the preferred syntax would be void Function() onSuccess).  That directly declares onSuccess as a function that returns void.

